# json is empty after a hard reboot

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, jackson

im using Jackson object mapper to save a json file into a raspberry pi file file is ok and is filled with data until i unplug the power to it. after plugging it back and checking the file it is empty.

```
    public static <T> void serialize(Path path, T object, Class<T> ref, StdSerializer<T> serializer) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(ref, serializer);
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);

    objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File(path.toString()), object);
}
```

Comment: You seem to not be mentioning a fair bit of important information. What OS are you running on the pi? Where are you saving your file? Is the pi configured to reset to a clean state? etc

Comment: Sorry forgot about that it's the latest version of rasbian and the file is saved under the boot folder

Comment: When you unplug FAT formatted USB disk drives from desktop OSes without ejecting you get corrupted file system. Try to use sync before powering it down without proper shutdown. This is full blown OS and boot folder maps to FAT formatted partition. Probably filesystem changes do not get written properly to the SD card in time. Probably you could tweak your fstab to force flushing of write cache often or to bypass write cache for this partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted to me above the problem was the fat filesystem when moving the save location into the home directory the problem didn't occur